# Widget test whether some widget is raster cached, and whether the cache has been refreshed

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I have some heavily painted widgets (lots of drawPath with complex paths etc) that are not updated very frequently. Therefore, I use `Transform(filterQuality: FilterQuality.none)` (suggested at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106006#issuecomment-1156558005) to enable raster cache.

The problem is, I want to have a widget test to check:

1. Is it really raster cached?
2. When I update the UI, is raster cache sometimes refreshed unwantedly even if content is identical? (For example, I may write down a buggy CustomPainter.shouldRepaint that returns `true` even if should not; and I may give CustomPainter a Listenable that notifyListener when not needed).

So how can I make assertions about these? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: post your `CustomPainter` code and how it is used inside your custom `StatefulWidget`

Comment: @pskink Just a normal CustomPainter used within a normal CustomPaint and so on. The question is about, *I want to check raster cache for arbitrary flutter widget trees*

Comment: @pskink isRepaintBoundry, or RepaintBoundry widget, is indeed not equivalent to raster cache. isRepaintBoundry=true can still result in non-raster-cached widgets

Comment: @pskink IMHO `paint` method is not "raster cache"... You can make a small experiment and will see it :)

Comment: Sorry, but that is about "painting", not "raster cache". I know repaintboundary will solve such unwanted repaints.

Comment: raster cache: well there is no explicit doc I guess, but it is everywhere. for example, in benchmarking output you will see raster cache consumption etc. and in flutter issues you see it as well e.g. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88832